# What's the difference between an orc and a goblin in the Lord of the Rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I mean, are there significant physical, mental, emotional (if any of them had emotions that is) differences that separate them?

Comment: Please use the correct tags.   If I'm not mistaken, you've been told to do so at least once already, and you have used inappropriate, vague tags like "books" and "movies" several times. If you're asking about LotR, use the "Lord-of-the-Rings" tag.  If you're asking about Star Wars, use "Star-Wars".

Comment: I've undeleted the question.  It can still help people find the accepted answer to this sort of question by directing them to the first question.